# aligning the the twitter widget in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm building the following project website http://hpsfo.bitbucket.org and would like to add the twitter widget as part of the navigation bar to cover the need for announcements, project updates, "what's new" etc. While adding the twitter widget I bump into two issues.

The first issue is that I can't find the way to vertically align the widget correctly even when I inline the style like this `<li style="vertical-align: middle;">`, what shall I do here to get the correct middle vertical alignment? The second issue is that upon loading, the style is shown incorrectly and then it "loads" the correct button style on the fly, you can see this unwanted effect by refreshing the page. How can I avoid this?

UPDATE: the second issue seems to be related to remotely loading the js file from the twitter server. I think I could solve this by simply inlining the file into my project website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just put

```
<li style="margin-top:10px;">
```

For performance issue, put as much as you can of your JS to the footer, so JS loads after the important stuff.

Comment: Thank you! it works now :) regarding the performance I put the include of the `widgets.js` but still I get the slow style loading effect?

Comment: This twitter follow button can be a problem. Just move everything inside <script></script> after the <a> link of the twitter follow into the footer and see if is better.
All social buttons can be trouble for page loading.